# App crashes on iOS with no internet connection

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I am using `async` method to retrieve `JSON` data , the data comes successfully but when I turn off the internet in my device, the App stops unfortunately. How can I handle this exception, or how can I handle internet Connectivity in Xamarin.Forms.

```
public partial class MainActivity : ContentPage
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Adverts> Zoos { get; set; }

        public int Count = 0;
        public short Counter = 0;
        public int SlidePosition = 0;
        string heightList;
        int heightRowsList = 90;

        private const string Url = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Mobile/Mobileapi.aspx?Action=Featured&Country=Uganda";
        private const string BaseImageUrl = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Images/app_images/";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        public ObservableCollection<Adverts> adverts;

        public MainActivity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            TrendingShows();

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {

                OnAppearing();
            }


            else
            {

                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert ", "No internet Connection Please", "OK");
            }






        }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
            {

                var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
                var adv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Adverts>>(content);

                adverts = new ObservableCollection<Adverts>(adv);



                AdvertsCarousel.ItemsSource = adverts;
                // attaching auto sliding on to carouselView 
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(18), () =>
                {
                    SlidePosition++;
                    if (SlidePosition == adverts.Count)
                        SlidePosition = 0;
                    AdvertsCarousel.Position = SlidePosition;
                    return true;
                });



            }
```

**i tried this but it seems not working , How can i handle this.**

Comment: Did you try `try catch`?

Comment: does try and catch check internet connectivity?

Comment: You either has to check if you have connectivity before trying to connect, or you need to use a `try catch` block to catch your exception, usually a `try catch` block will do the job.

Comment: I have update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a simple try/catch construction, this also helps for any other errors that might occur. Or look into the [Connectivity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin). This has some methods, properties and events to determine what the state of your connection is and you can handle your content accordingly.

*Edit*

As a follow up to your edited question; you do not need to call `OnAppearing` yourself. Either abstract your code to some kind of method that refreshes the data if you need to, or find another method that is better suitable.

You should also move your check closer to the point where you are fetching your data. For instance, do it more like this:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    adverts = new List<Adverts>();

    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var adv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Adverts>>(content);

        adverts = new ObservableCollection<Adverts>(adv);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Either show cached adverts here, or hide your carrousel or whatever you want to do when there is no connection
    }

    AdvertsCarousel.ItemsSource = adverts;

    // attaching auto sliding on to carouselView 
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(18), () =>
    {
        SlidePosition++;
        if (SlidePosition == adverts.Count)
            SlidePosition = 0;
        AdvertsCarousel.Position = SlidePosition;
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: yes i looked at that plugin , how can i use an IF on an async method

Comment: Why is that different from using it on a non-async method? Just await it and retrieve the result. Also the `IsConnected` property is not async, you can just check it to see if you're connected at that moment.

Comment: can you please show me by an example , me i just called  `OnAppearing();` in the class constructor immediately after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: What confuses me is that how can i really call the async method in the IF o Try catch , the way i see this it;s like async method just runs already in the page background , so i dont know how to handle it as a method

Comment: You do not need to call OnAppearing yourself, move the check for IsConnected to where you get your data.

Comment: So you mean on these lines `var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
                var adv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Adverts>>(content);

                adverts = new ObservableCollection<Adverts>(adv);`

Comment: Thats where i see how i am getting my data.